# Escaping special characters in cron

Tags: shell, cron

I use the following commands to copy the entire directory to another server.

Sending server:

```
cd /var/log/ && tar c mysql > to_analyse.tar && nc 10.10.10.99 1236 < to_analyse.tar
```

Receiving server:

```
mkdir -p /var/log/splunk/from_217 && cd /var/log/splunk/from_217 && nc  -l 1236 > to_analyse.tar && tar -xf to_analyse.tar
```

It is working as expected. 
But when I add it to cron (copy paste with appropriate times), it does not work.

Comment: It's usually the best idea to simply put it all in a script, and call the script from cron. You'll get predictable better supported results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several things to check when using cron:

1- The user that is executing the cron job. This will affect the privileges assigned to the cron jobs.

2- The environment variables. Some scripts command may require some environment variables to work as expected.

3- It is better to refer to binaries/scripts using full path instead of just its name like `mkdir` and `nc`. I am not saying it will not work. It may or may not depending on the `PATH` definition and binary location.

Comment: `cd` is always just `cd` since it's a shell built-in.  You may have a `cd` executable, but it's purpose is to test whether you can cd into a given directory (by checking the return value).